# Reading in multiple data types from a txt file Java

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop, java.util.scanner, token

I know there are many questions already on simply reading data from a txt file, but the txt file I was given contains this:

```
1980 Aug    945 100 Allen1983 Aug   962 100 Alicia1984 Sep  949 100 Diana
```

The first number is a year, the a month, a wind pressure, wind speed in knots, and name of hurricane. This pattern goes for a few hundred entries and I have to get each different figure into its own array (years[], months[], pressure[], etc...)

I've tried many different ways, but here is an example of a recent attempt I did:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Hurricanes2 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { 
int i = 0;
    int token1 = 0;
    String token2 = "";

    int[] years = new int[1000]; //token 1
    String[] months = new String[1000]; //token 2
    String[] names = new String[1000];
    int[] pressure = new int[1000]; //token 1
    int[] windSpeed = new int[1000]; //token 1
    int[] category = new int[1000]; //token 1

    Scanner s = new Scanner (new FileReader("hurcdata2.txt"));

while (s.hasNext()) {
        if (s.hasNextInt()) {
            token1 = s.nextInt();
            if (token1 >= 1980) {
                years[i] = token1;
            }
            else if (token1 >= 1000) {
                pressure[i] = token1;
            }
            else {
                windSpeed[i] = token1;
            }
        }
        else if (s.hasNext()) {
            token2 = s.next();
            if (token2.equals("Jun") || token2.equals("Jul") || token2.equals("Aug") || token2.equals("Sep") || token2.equals("Oct") || token2.equals("Nov")) {
                months[i] = token2;
            }
            else {
                names[i] = token2;
            }
        }
        token1 = 0;
        token2 = "";
        i++;
        }
```

When I print any array using a for-each loop, all the values are 0. Except when I print just the first element (e.g. a[0]) it will show the correct value. Any other where the index > 0 still shows 0.
I know there is much wrong with it but at this point I was trying some weird things to get it to work. I'm not looking for a correction to this code as much as a solution to the problem overall.

Comment: Did you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I tried, but there were no errors. Once I pressed step it ran the whole code

Comment: Just because there was no "error" does not mean there is not an issue.  Obviously there is an issue because you are posting a question.  Step through every line of code, examine the variables as they change, etc. Learning proper debugging techniques is just as important as learning the language. http://blog.codeunion.io/2014/09/03/teaching-novices-how-to-debug-code/

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting the words at the spaces, and then storing it in an array of `Objects`. You can then use `instanceof` to compare the type, e.g. `if(obj instanceof Integer)`...